# Upload picture to SQL Server database using Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been trying to upload pictures to a SQL Server database by using Entity Framework.

I tried to take the picture and convert it from `IFormFile` in the DtoModel to `byte[]` in the primary model to store it in the database but it doesn't work and I get an "invalid value".

I used this logical method in the ASP.NET Web API many times and it's working smoothly, so I can't figure out what I miss here.

Primary model:

```
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
       
        public string Name { get; set; }
   
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Photo is required.")]
        public byte[] Pic { get; set; }

        public string PicFromat { get; set; }
```

DtoModel:

```
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Pics { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
private new List<string> _allowedExtenstions = new List<string> { ".jpg", ".png" }; 
private long _maxAllowedPosterSize = 1048576;

public propertiesController(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create( dtoprop model)
{
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View( model);
        }

        if(!_allowedExtenstions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(model.Pics.FileName.ToLower())))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Pic", "Only .PNG, .JPG images are allowed!");
    
            return View(model);
        }
    
        if (model.Pics.Length > _maxAllowedPosterSize)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Pic", "Poster cannot be more than 1 MB!");
            return View(model);
        }

        using var dataStream = new MemoryStream();

        await model.Pics.CopyToAsync(dataStream);

        var pic = new property
        {
            Name = model.Name,
            Pic = dataStream.ToArray()
        };

        _context.Properties.Add(pic);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The `Create.cshtml`:

```
@model EshopTest5.Data.dtoprop

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>property</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PicFromat" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="PicFromat" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PicFromat" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>



            <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" asp-for="Pic" accept=".png, .jpg" />
                <label class="custom-file-label" asp-for="Pic"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Pic" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>


           

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your form doesn't seem to have the multipart/form-data enctype. Posting files requires this. Let me know if this fixes your issue, I'd make an answer of this comment

Comment: @WiktorZychla unfortunately it didn't help it gave me in the interface "The Pics field is required"

Comment: You need to add `method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form,And since the property name is `Pics`,you need to change `asp-for="Pic"` with `asp-for="Pics"`.

Answer (score -2):

I personally would advice you add a client side validation for `_allowedExtenstions` not just a server side validation so the user does not waste his/her data bundle posting the formdata to the server only to get back a validation error

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create( dtoprop model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View( model);
        }

        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        model.Pics.File.CopyTo(stream);
        stream.Position = 0;
        var byteData = stream.ToArray();

        var pic = new property
        {
            Name = model.Name,
            Pic = byteData
        };

        _context.Properties.Add(pic);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
```

and you should add  `enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"` to your html form.

Comment: This should have been a comment as it doesn't answer the question

Comment: i don't have enough reputation for that

Comment: You should have both client and sever side validation so that it is not trivial to bypass.

Comment: If you don't have enough reputation to comment, then don't don't use an answer as a workaround. Just wait until you have enough reputation to comment. And make sure that the advice you're posting is actually good advice advice: client side validation is a supplement to server side validation, never a replacement for it!

Comment: @Crowcoder can you explain more, please?

Comment: I'll explain: client side validation is not a replacement for server side validation because client side validation happens on the client's computer, and thus the client can bypass it with ease. It's simple to disable validation, or even craft an entire HTTP request using tools like Postman or Burpsuite. Servers should never trust client input, they must always validate. So while you may offer client side validation out of convenience, it is not a substitute for server side validation: only a supplement for it.